# efficient text loading without line separators

Tags: java, android, text

so I have a fairly big (4mb) txt with data for a monolingual dictionary. Because the explanations of the words are split into multiple lines i can't read it line by line. On the other hand I have "###" separators which I can use.

My question is: what is the most efficient way to load this text into a map in java/android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load file to single String and use `split("###")` method on it. It gives you array of strings split by your separator. 4 Mb is OK to load it in memory at once.

```
byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
String fileContents = new String(encoded, encoding);
String[] lines = fileContents.split("###");
```

**Update**: not sure you can use that code to read file on android - it's for Java SE 7. On android can use code like this:

```
FileInputStream fis;
fis = openFileInput(filePath);
StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

while ((n = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
{ 
  fileContent.append(new String(buffer, 0, n)); 
}
String[] lines = fileContent.toString().split("###");
```